# Set distinct ID in index view in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two models and I combine them in one view model as shown below:

```
public class VotSourceRegistersVM
{
    public VotSources VotSources { get; set; }
    public VotContacts VotContacts { get; set; }
    public VotPayers VotPayers { get; set; }
}
```

My controller for index as shown below:

```
public async Task< IActionResult> Index()
{
    List<VotSources> VotSources = _context.VotSources.ToList();
    List<VotContacts> VotContacts = _context.VotContacts.ToList();

    var VotSourceRegistersVM = from p in VotSources
                               join c in VotContacts on p.ID equals c.VotSourcesId into table
                               from c in table.Distinct()
                               select new VotSourceRegistersVM { VotSources = p, VotContacts = c };
    return View(VotSourceRegistersVM);
}
```

My index view as below:

```html
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th >
                Kod Dana
            </th>
            <th >
                Nama Organisasi
            </th >
            <th >
                PIC
            </th>
            <th >
                Status
            </th>
            <th >
                Tindakan
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.VotSources.Code)
                
            </td>                                 
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.VotSources.Name)
                
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.VotContacts.Name)

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.VotContacts.Status)
            </td>
            <td>  
                <a href="/Vot/VotSources/Edit/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.VotContacts.VotSourcesId)" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Vot/VotSources/Details/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.VotContacts.VotSourcesId)" class="btn btn-dark text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <button id="btnDel" class="btn btn-danger text-white" data-deleteID="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.VotContacts.VotSourcesId)" style="cursor:pointer">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I got 23 entries in my DB but there is 48 entries in my Index View
[image: I got 23 entries in my DB but there is 48 entries in my Index View]

I'm using linq to combine two table and display. The problem is my view data showing the duplicated ID. How can i distinct ID in controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task< IActionResult> Index()
{
    List<VotSources> VotSources = _context.VotSources.ToList();
    List<VotContacts> VotContacts = _context.VotContacts.ToList();

    var VotSourceRegistersVM = (from p in VotSources
                               join c in VotContacts on p.ID equals c.VotSourcesId into table
                               from c in table.Distinct()
                               select new VotSourceRegistersVM { VotSources = p, VotContacts = c }).Distinct().ToList();
    return View(VotSourceRegistersVM);
}
```

Comment: i try yours and the index view still show the same number of entries.